# Check value if reached limit result from forEach using google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data consists of Date and Time on a separate column. My problem is how to get the data which reached its limit.

link for the data (google sheet): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lEfzjG1zzJVPMN8r-OpeZm6q9_IqSwk9DNCEY-q7ozY/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried this code in Google Apps Script:

Google Script:

```
function timeCheck(){
  var lookup = "August 28, 2019";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");  

  var myData = ws.getRange(2, 7, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();

  myData.forEach(function(row){
  var lookup = "August 28, 2019"; //this is just a sample search data
  var dte = new Date (row[0]);
  var form = Utilities.formatDate(dte, 'GMT+8', 'MMMM dd, yyyy');
     if(form == lookup){
       Logger.log(row)
    }
  });
}
```

then I got the following Log:

```
[19-08-26 15:14:04:073 HKT] [Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 8:00 AM]
[19-08-26 15:14:04:073 HKT] [Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 9:00 AM]
[19-08-26 15:14:04:074 HKT] [Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 10:00 AM]
[19-08-26 15:14:04:075 HKT] [Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 8:00 AM]
[19-08-26 15:14:04:076 HKT] [Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 8:00 AM]
[19-08-26 15:14:04:077 HKT] [Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 9:00 AM]
[19-08-26 15:14:04:077 HKT] [Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 9:00 AM]
```

My problem now is how I cant get the value in `row[1]`, which is the time,  which reached 3 times. In the example above I would like to  get the `8:00 AM` and `9:00 AM`since they are the values which reached the limit.

Thank you in advance for your help. I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: `above I should get the 8:00 AM and 9:00 AM.` Why?

Comment: @TheMaster, I am trying to get the values which reached the limit. so that I can use that value for my match item for my other code. Im still looking for a solution. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Or do you have any suggestion where I can get the `lookup` value in my data and check it if its `row[1]` reached 3 times? sorry if im not too clear. I dont know how to formulate it into question.

Comment: Can I ask you about your expected value from your shared Spreadsheet?

Comment: Sample value of  `limit` and `row[1]`?

Comment: @Tanaike Once I get the Date and Time which exist 3 times in the `Test_Data` Sheet, the program will search the result Date in the `Time_Select` Sheet and change the value of the Time in its column. in the shared Spreadsheet, the August 28 exist multiple times but the time 8:00AM and 9:00AM both exists 3 times so in the 'Time_Select' sheet under August 28, 2019, I would like to change the Value `8:00AM` and `9:00AM`  to "Not Available"

Comment: @TheMaster No Date Limit but the Time limit is 3 times. the `row[1]` values in my code when logging it are the time.

Answer (score 1):

I got my problem solved by using `push` method and the code I got from @Christopher Bradley in one of my questions here.

Here is the update on the code I used:

```
function timeCheck(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");  
  var myData = ws.getRange(2, 7, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();
  var arrData = [];
  myData.forEach(function(row){

  var lookup = "Aug 28, 2019";
  var dte = new Date (row[0]);
  var form = Utilities.formatDate(dte, 'GMT+8', 'MMM dd, yyyy');

    if(form == lookup){
      arrData.push(row[1]); 
    }    
  });
  var myVals = arrData;
  var CheckLimitReached = function (V)
  {
    var records= {};
    V.forEach(function (x) { records[x] = (records[x] || 0) + 1; });
    var limit_reached = Object.keys(records).filter(function (R) {
      return records[R] >= 3;});
    return limit_reached;

  };
   var dataDisable = CheckLimitReached(myVals);
  Logger.log(dataDisable);

}
```